# clang-format: Remove space between ')' and '{' in function declaration

Tags: c, clang-format

I installed clang-format and I found settings `-style=LLVM` close to my coding style.

**But I don't need a space between ')' and '{' in function declaration.**

Checked official help (https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) and not found about this.

**Q:** What key should I write in `.clang-format`? or need rewrite source of clang-format?

Command:

```
[Linux]   cat HelloWorld.c | clang-format -style=LLVM
[Windows] type HelloWorld.c | clang-format -style=LLVM
```

Input:

```
void main(){printf("Hello, world!");return;}
```

Output:

```
void main() {
           ^
  printf("Hello, world!");
  return;
}
```

I want to:

```
void main(){
           ^
  printf("Hello, world!");
  return;
}
```

Note: "^" is not output. Added for readability.

Comment: offtopic: I am with `clang-format` on this. With space is better than without.

Comment: Why would you want that? It's an irregular formatting style, and of [all the indentation styles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style), some of which are exceedingly strange, none do this. Formatting it without the space is going to look like a mistake to anyone familiar with C style code bases. Remember, as C is extremely sensitive to tiny "details" like `=` and `==`, so are C programmers.

Comment: In my organization and its surroundings, using this style in long time. Currently I can't change this.

Comment: Seems like this is something an IDE could/might take care of. Not sure if `clang-format` can do the trick.